# using pytest to check if sqlite database created or not

Tags: python, class, pytest

I'm creating a CRUD program using python and sqlite database, my code works just fine, but I don't know how to use pytest to check if the database file has been created after using the connect function

I'm new to pytestand I only use it for simple function

so I try to use it with another function that creates a CSV  file to check if the file has been created I can't figure it out how to fix the problem of the path
this is my class

```
class Crud_db:
    def __init__(self, database = 'database.db'):
        self.database = database

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        # print('connect seccesfully')

    def execute(self, query):
        self.query = query
        self.cursor.execute(self.query)

    def close(self): 
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()

    def save_to_csv(self, day = None):
        if day == None:
            query_general_bill_all = ''' SELECT * FROM  general_bill'''
            query_expences_all = ''' SELECT * FROM expenses '''
            query_total_all = ''' SELECT * FROM total '''

            df1 = pd.read_sql(query_general_bill_all, sqlite3.connect(self.database))
            df1.to_csv('general_bill_all.csv', index = False)

            df2 = pd.read_sql(query_expences_all, sqlite3.connect(self.database))
            df2.to_csv('expenses_all.csv', index = False)

            df3 = pd.read_sql(query_total_all, sqlite3.connect(self.database))
            df3.to_csv('total_day_all.csv', index = False)
        if day :
            try:
                day = str(day)
                query_general_bill_all = f" SELECT * FROM  general_bill WHERE date_g == '{day}'"
                query_expences_all = f' SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE date == "{day}" '
                query_total_all = f' SELECT * FROM total WHERE date == "{day}" '

                df1 = pd.read_sql(query_general_bill_all, sqlite3.connect(self.database))
                # print(df1)
                df1.to_csv(f'general_bill_{day}.csv', index = False)

                df2 = pd.read_sql(query_expences_all, sqlite3.connect(self.database))
                df2.to_csv(f'expenses_{day}.csv', index = False)

                df3 = pd.read_sql(query_total_all, sqlite3.connect(self.database))
                df3.to_csv(f'total_day_{day}.csv', index = False)
            except ValueError:
                sys.exit('value Error')
```

and this my test so far

```
import pytest
import sqlite3

from class_helper import Crud_db

db = Crud_db() 


def test_tables():
    db.connect()
    query = """ SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' """
    db.execute(query)
    result = db.cursor.fetchall()

    # print(result)
    
    assert len(result) == 8


class TestFile(object):

    def test_my_function(self, tmpdir):

        test_path = tmpdir.join('F:/final_project')
        save_csv = db.save_to_csv()

        save_csv

        assert test_path.read() == 'expenses_all'
```

the `class TestFile`dont work and give me this error

```
platform win32 Python 3.8.8, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: F:\final_project
collected 2 items

test_project.py .F                                                                                                                             [100%]

===================================================================== FAILURES ====================================================================== 
_____________________________________________________________ TestFile.test_my_function _____________________________________________________________ 

self = <module 'py.error'>, func = <built-in function open>
args = ('C:\\Users\\Zakaria\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pytest-of-Zakaria\\pytest-0\\test_my_function0', 'r'), kwargs = {}, __tracebackhide__ = False      
cls = <class 'py.error.EBUSY'>, value = PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'), tb = <traceback object at 0x000001E0444A22C0>, errno = 13

    def checked_call(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        """ call a function and raise an errno-exception if applicable. """
        __tracebackhide__ = True
        try:
>           return func(*args, **kwargs)
E           PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Zakaria\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pytest-of-Zakaria\\pytest-0\\test_my_function0' 

lib\site-packages\py\_error.py:66: PermissionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

self = <test_project.TestFile object at 0x000001E05EBEB3D0>
tmpdir = local('C:\\Users\\Zakaria\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pytest-of-Zakaria\\pytest-0\\test_my_function0')

    def test_my_function(self, tmpdir):

        test_path = tmpdir.join('')
        save_csv = db.save_to_csv()

        save_csv

>       assert test_path.read() == 'expenses_all'

test_project.py:31:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:176: in read
    with self.open(mode) as f:
lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:369: in open
    return py.error.checked_call(open, self.strpath, mode)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <module 'py.error'>, func = <built-in function open>
args = ('C:\\Users\\Zakaria\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pytest-of-Zakaria\\pytest-0\\test_my_function0', 'r'), kwargs = {}, __tracebackhide__ = False      
cls = <class 'py.error.EBUSY'>, value = PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'), tb = <traceback object at 0x000001E0444A22C0>, errno = 13

    def checked_call(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        """ call a function and raise an errno-exception if applicable. """
        __tracebackhide__ = True
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except self.Error:
            raise
        except (OSError, EnvironmentError):
            cls, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
            if not hasattr(value, 'errno'):
                raise
            __tracebackhide__ = False
            errno = value.errno
            try:
                if not isinstance(value, WindowsError):
                    raise NameError
            except NameError:
                # we are not on Windows, or we got a proper OSError
                cls = self._geterrnoclass(errno)
            else:
                try:
                    cls = self._geterrnoclass(_winerrnomap[errno])
                except KeyError:
                    raise value
>           raise cls("%s%r" % (func.__name__, args))
E           py.error.EBUSY: [Resource device]: open('C:\\Users\\Zakaria\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pytest-of-Zakaria\\pytest-0\\test_my_function0', 'r')  

lib\site-packages\py\_error.py:86: EBUSY
============================================================== short test summary info ============================================================== 
FAILED test_project.py::TestFile::test_my_function - py.error.EBUSY: [Resource device]: open('C:\Users\Zakaria\AppData\Local\Temp\pytest-of-Z...
============================================================ 1 failed, 1 passed in 2.74s ============================================================
```

Comment: Is the `save_to_csv` production code or just test code mixed into production code?
The permission errorsare maybe because the csv file is not close properly?
If you want to check that the database file is created, can't you just write a test that deletes it and then checks if it exists after calling the connect function? Or even better: Use mocking to check if the connect function has been called?

Comment: No, that's the closest thing I can get to a testing function that can check if a file created after facing a function, I really don't know how I can check how to check if the database there or not